# Grafana displays No Data from Prometheus Under 6 hours time period

Tags: centos, grafana, prometheus

I have a Prometheus Dashboard that will display No Data when viewing it on a remote machine and the time period is 6 hours or less. The issue does not happen on the local machine. Grafana and Prometheus service are both running on the same CentOS 7 server. I've tested this on Windows and Linux machines

Edit: Setting range to 12hrs doesn't populate the data properly, but 24hrs and more does

Comment: It could be that the clocks and/or time zones of the two machines are different and Grafana is actually requesting different time ranges from one machine vs. the other. It's not something I've seen, just speculating.

Comment: I did notice that no matter how I set the time it wouldn't match with the servers time...